# Conversion of a Varchar Datatype to a datetime resultant in an out of range

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, exception, datetime-parsing

I have problem. I can' identify my mistake...

```
int dt = Convert.ToInt32(Items.Rows[T1]["F14"].ToString().Trim());
int mn = Convert.ToInt32(Items.Rows[T1]["F15"].ToString().Trim());
int yr = Convert.ToInt32(Items.Rows[T1]["F16"].ToString().Trim());
string DtString = mn.ToString().Trim() + "/" + dt.ToString().Trim() + "/" + yr.ToString().Trim();
DateTime RegExp = Convert.ToDateTime(DtString);

exp_date is datetime field in sqlserver.

string MyDtQry = "UPDATE MyTable SET exp_date='" + RegExp + "' where MyTable.id_no='" + AlmIDNo + "'";
```

But I'am getting the error:

> Conversion of a Varchar Datatype to a datetime resultant in an out of range

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I would approach the task very differently:

- After getting the day, month and year as integers I definitely *wouldn't* stick them back together and parse them. Just use:

  ```
  // Note the meaningful variable names here, btw...
  DateTime date = new DateTime(year, month, day);
  ```
- When updating the database, I *wouldn't* put the value directly into the SQL statement. Use a parameterized SQL statement instead, and set the parameter to `date`. That way you don't need to worry about the database expecting a different date format to the one you provide. In general, you should *always* use parameterized SQL rather than embedding the values directly into the SQL - as well as helping with this kind of situation, it avoids SQL injection attacks.

Now, *after* doing all of that, if you're still getting an error, you should check what actual data you're trying to insert. Maybe the data in `Items` really *is* out of range for SQL Server.

Answer (score 2):

It is hard to see *exactly* since you don't show any of your inputs; however, the following is clearly dangerous:

```
DateTime RegExp = Convert.ToDateTime(DtString);

string MyDtQry = "UPDATE MyTable SET exp_date='" + RegExp + "' where MyTable.id_no='" + AlmIDNo + "'";
```

Even if we gloss over the fact that you should be using parameters (you really should), you would need to format this date in the way that SQL server expects - which could be very different to the local format.

However; don't bother formatting it! Use a parameter for this, and it'll go away. This doesn't need to be hard - for example [with dapper](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/):

```
DateTime RegExp = new DateTime(yr, mn, dt);

connection.Execute("UPDATE MyTable SET exp_date=@exp where MyTable.id_no=@id",
    new { exp = RegExp, id = AlmIDNo });
```

and done; fully safe from both injection and the (more likely in this case) issue of formatting data as strings.

Answer (score 1):

This must be problem of the format you are specifying, like instead of month column you might be saving date value column.